# Meteor: Autoform-Cloudinary not getting cloud name / API key from settings

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, cloudinary

I'm using the Autoform-Cloudinary package on a clean new Meteor project. My code is exactly the same as the example code, with the template added to the end of the default "Welcome to Meteor" page.

I have only added the following packages (nothing removed).

```
cosio55:autoform-cloudinary
aldeed:simple-schema
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
check
```

I get the following error when trying to add an image:

> POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/undefined/auto/upload 401 (Unauthorized)

The "undefined" suggests that Cloudinary is not registering my cloud name, but
I have loaded settings.json and can log my cloudinary cloud name on the console using:

```
console.log(Meteor.settings.public.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I've done wrong. Any suggestions highly appreciated!

Edit: Here is my settings.json file

```
{
  "public": {
    "CLOUDINARY_API_KEY": "9xxxxxxxxxxxxx1",
    "CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME": "dxxxxxxxu"
  },

  "CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET": "Ixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Alastair_Ong Can you show how your settings.json is structured? Make sure to obfuscate the confidential information.

Comment: Ok edited for settings.json.